# Project-specific variables and how to read - write them

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I really couldn't find anything like how to use easily storable variables for each "project" I create. I need to store per project some computed "variables" and by some other script read (load) them, all from some /path/ (on hard drive).

I know I can do that in CSV but that's not clean.  If I store 10+ strings in CSV, it becomes not editable. I would like to see something rather transposed like variable = value on each row, easy to read/write with options (do not overwrite if it's there etc).

Comment: You can use a psd1 file

Comment: As per above, a psd1 with a hashtable in it for your parameters and `Import-PowerShellDataFile` to load up that file. Other than that, for the key = value format, you can use `ConvertFrom-StringData`. For importing, that does it but if you want to export, there is no built-in way with these two. You either need to do some additional work. I'd be more inclined to use JSON as the preferred format for a config file. That you can import and export rather easily and it is relatively clean to edit manually and very easy to integrate with other stuff.